# How to exclude crawling of some pages

Tags: wordpress, web-crawler

Am using wordpress, and through admin setting , enable Search Engine Visibility to avoid crawling of pages. And when we check page source also, there is code like

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"/>
```

But still google crawling all my pages. How to stop this. I need to hide all the user pages crawling, the pages of user after logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Your meta tag should look like this

`<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>`

Also update your robots.txt appropriately. Say you don't want Google to index `/posts/1`, then your robots.txt would be

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /posts/1
```

Comment: Is it possible to allow some specific pages only? lot of user pages is there , so   `````````                                                                                                                    
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Disallow: /                                                                                                     
```````````````                                                                                                                like this can we add pages that want to allow?

Comment: yes you can. What you can do is  

User-Agent: Googlebot
Allow: /tags/
Allow: /categories/
Allow: /comments/